# Angular testing service which overwrites console.log (Jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've an Angular logging service which overwrites console.log and others depending on an environment constant, simplified example:

```
if(!DEBUG_ENV) {
    console.log = function(){}; 
}
```

So my question is how can I test with Jasmine that console.log is actually getting overwritten to this empty function by my service. I've mocked my constant and injected my service, but I can't really figure out how to test if console.log is being overwritten with Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by mocking up $window and then overwrite $window in my service instead of overwriting console[whatever] directly like following:

```
$provide.value('$window', {
    console: {
      log: function(){return 'enabled'};
    }
});
```

Then I injected this into my service like this:

```
inject(['$window', function($window) {
   _window = $window;
}]);
```

Then in my service I could do following:

```
if(!DEBUG_ENV) {
   $window.console.log = function(){return 'disabled'};
}
```

And lastly I could check if all happened as intended by checking what my injected mock of $window returned either 'enabled' or 'disabled'.

```
expect( _window.console.log() ).toEqual('disabled');
```